# Access TypeA properties in `Expression<Func<TypeA,TypeB>>`

Tags: c#

Access TypeA properties  in `Expression<Func<TypeA,TypeB>>`.

In the following ProjectorAB class from TypeA to TypeB. I want to access TypeA properties like I would with a `return t => new {...}`.

```
public static class ProjectorAB
{
    public static Expression<Func<TypeA, TypeB>> Projection
    {
        get
        {  
            var tInfo = new TypeB_SubInfo
            {
                prop1 = "",
                // ...
                prop5 = "",
            };

            var tItems = new List<TypeB_SubItem>()
            {                    
            };

            return new TypeB
            {
                Items = tItems,
                Info = tInfo,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It feels I am missing the obvious. And yes I can make it a method but that take a parameter TypeA and return TypeB. But wont solve my issue how to make some multi line statement in a  `Expression<Func<TypeA,TypeB>>`

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking or what you're trying to do. Are you trying to create a new expression? Or modify an existing one? Are you trying to compile and execute an `Expression`?

Comment: It's the creation of a new one. I have one working with the `return t => new {...}`. But I want to clarify the code by separating the statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to create an `Expression<>` is with the implicit conversion from a lambda arrow `=>` into the relevant `Expression<>`. But the right-hand side of the `=>` arrow most be a "simple" expression, not a block `{ … }`.

Without the `Expression<>` you could make a plain `Func<>` delegate instance like this:

```
public static Func<TypeA, TypeB> Projection
{
  get
  {   
    return someTypeA =>
    {
      var tInfo = new TypeB_SubInfo
      {
        prop1 = someTypeA.Whatever,
        // ...
        prop5 = someTypeA.Foobar,
      };

      var tItems = new List<TypeB_SubItem>()
      {                    
      };

      return new TypeB
      {
        Items = tItems,
        Info = tInfo,
      };
    };
  }
}
```

When you want an expression tree, you must rewrite to something like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<TypeA, TypeB>> Projection
{
  get
  {   
    return someTypeA => new TypeB
    {
      Info = new TypeB_SubInfo
      {
        prop1 = someTypeA.Whatever,
        // ...
        prop5 = someTypeA.Foobar,
      },

      Items = new List<TypeB_SubItem>()
      {                    
      },
    };
  }
}
```